# Best way to handle this VS2010 question now that SP1 was released

Tags: discussion

I have a question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9378/what-usability-issues-have-you-had-with-vs2010/58285#58285) that I've used lobby for fixes in VS2010 SP1.  I haven't yet gone through the release notes to determine what has been fixed in SP1 or not.

What is the best action that should be taken on a question that refers to a product that is one version behind current?

Answer (score 3):

I would edit the body of the question to note which issues have been fixed in SP1 and edit the title to reflect the fact that it applies to the stock version of VS2010. At that point, the question could be locked to prevent further edits/new answers. You'll have to flag it for a moderator to have that done.

I think since SP1 doesn't come bundled with VS2010, it may still be beneficial to keep the question around in case anyone needs help justifying an upgrade to their boss or something along those lines.